# Need to Map HTML Content with existing HTML element in java

Tags: java, java-8

```
String mainString = "<b color="#78904">Main Page</b><div>This is a Main Page</div>";

String insideString = Jsoup.parse(mainString).text();
```

insideString will return

> Main Page This is a Main Page

.

and I have highlighting few parts in the insideString like this based upon keyword. Here I'm took **i** is a user search keyword.`Th<mark>i</mark>s <mark>i</mark>s a Ma<mark>i</mark>n Page`.

Now what i want to do means , I'm need to map this highlighlighted string with my mainstring.

The **output** should become like

```
<b color="#78904">Ma<mark>i</mark>n Page</b><div>Th<mark>i</mark>s <mark>i</mark>s a Ma<mark>i</mark>n Page</div>
```

Comment: String replaceString=insideString.replace(keyword,"<mark>"+keyword+"</mark>");//replaces all occurrences of keyword to "<mark>"+keyword+"</mark>"

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht Again m need to map with my original string which is mainString